# Faucet handle turns entire base

Tags: faucet

I have a Delta kitchen faucet and when I turn the arm (A in the picture below), the on-off lever turns as well (B). It should just be turning A. I can't seem to find the exact model, but knowing the builder in our neighborhood, it's probably the cheapest one they can find.

Is that something I can repair so the arm swivels freely instead of turning the entire thing?

[image: Kitchen faucet]

Here is an image from beneath the sink.

[image: View underneath the sink]

Answer (score 1):

There will be a nut underneath the faucet, accessible from inside the cabinet. You'll need to tighten it. It won't be easy to get to and you'll probably need a specialty wrench. If this is a new home, get the builder back there to tighten it up. Pictures from under the cabinet to the faucet might clarify the situation more clearly.

Comment: Just before you do that - though I have very little doubt it is the correct diagnosis - put your finger on the small ring round the very bottom of the faucet as you are looking at it in that photo & just confirm that is spinning too. https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcbC4.png

Comment: Thanks Jack and Tetsujin. I've updated my question with a second picture from underneath the sink. The ring at the bottom does turn when I move the handle. Also, I don't see any bolts beneath the sink - only two screws, both of which are tight.

Comment: @Jeff  there's a big brass nut, well not really a nut like you're used to, on the stem. Try loosening those two screws and then tighten that brass nut. Then tighten the two screws.

Comment: Is the brass nut you're referring to what the screws are screwed into? If so, I'd assume I'll need to remove those screws completely and not just loosen them? And thanks again!

Comment: @Jeff  If the screws go into the counter, then yes, completely remove them.

Comment: @JACK: tightening those screws may be what's needed, Ive seen where they smoosh the upper plate against the counter, and the element they thread through is fixed in distance from the topside of the fixture

Comment: @whatsisname   The OP has said that those screws were tight so by loosening them and tightening up the nut, taking up some slack, might allow the screws to be tightened up against the counter more.